# c++ class for storing any class from class hierarchy

Tags: c++, c++11

let's suppose i have class hierarchy.
A; B1,B2,B3-Bn all derived from A, and some C classes derived from differrent B's.
I want to have a class "UnifiedStorage" to store A derived classes, that should not be templated, but it should have std::shared_ptr inside himself and have two functions:

```
template <typename T>
setData(std::shared_ptr<T> data/* A's derived class */)

template <typename T>
std::weak_ptr<T> getData()
```

only possible realization i have found is to create smth like Keeper:

```
class UnifiedStorage{
    class Keeper {
    public:
        virtual ~Keeper (){
        }
    };

    template <typename DataType>
    class SpecificKeeper : public Keeper {
    public:
        SpecificKeeper (std::shared_ptr<DataType> data): data(data) {}
        ~SpecificKeeper() = default;
        std::shared_ptr<DataType> data;
    };

    template <typename SpecificDataType>
    void setData (std::shared_ptr <SpecificDataType> d) {
        keeper.reset( new SpecificKeeper <SpecificDataType> (d) );
    }
    template <typename RequestedDataType>
    std::shared_ptr <RequestedDataType> getData () {
        SpecificKeeper <RequestedDataType>* specificKeeper =  dynamic_cast <SpecificKeeper <RequestedDataType> * > (keeper.data());
        if (specificKeeper == nullptr){
            return std::shared_ptr <RequestedDataType> ();
        }else{
            return specificKeeper->data;
        }
    }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Keeper> keeper;
}
```

But this realization has strong negative. I only able to get shared_ptr to type that i have set in setData.

For example if a have called `setData<B>(std::shared_ptr<B>)` i can't `getData<A>` it returns null, but if I will call `setData<A>(std::shared_ptr<B>)` `getData<A>` will return correct pointer.

Comment: Couldn't you just use: `void setData(std::shared_ptr<A> ptr) { m_data = ptr; } template <typename T> std::weak_ptr<T> getData() { return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(m_data); }`, being the member `std::shared_ptr<A> m_data;`?

Comment: I've got an *evil* one: have `std::function<void()>` and store `{ throw *this }`. Not to be used in real-life code, just for completeness and the next IOCCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue boils down to a very simple fact.

In your example `B1` derives from `A`. `B1` is a subclass of `A`.

However, `std::shared_ptr<B1>` is not a subclass of `std::shared_ptr<A>`. Neither is `SpecificKeeper<B1>` is a subclass of `SpecificKeeper<A>`. That's not how C++ works. Hence you cannot `dynamic_cast` from one to another.

The solution is to get rid of the templates completely, and simply store `std::shared_ptr<A>` in the keeper class, then do a `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` upon retrieval.

An abbreviated example should make it clear:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A { public: virtual ~A() {} };

class B : public A {};

class C : public A {};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b{new B};

    std::shared_ptr<A> a=b;

    std::shared_ptr<C> c=std::dynamic_pointer_cast<C>(a);

    std::cout << a.get() << std::endl; // Stored base pointer
    std::cout << c.get() << std::endl; // This will be nullptr, conversion failed
}
```

So, your `UnifiedStorage` simply needs to store `std::shared_ptr<A>`. It doesn't need a template class for that.

`GetData()` will attempt to `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` the stored pointer to the requested type. If the `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` succeeds, you have your shared pointer. If not, you get a null `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: excuse me, maybe you can also help me. what if i want to store not only A only derived classes? how can i solve this problem without solution like "Any type" implementation(usually based on void*)